# Django : Cannot import name <ModelName>

Tags: python, django

Hi guys I am having an issue importing a model, I think is something related to circular imports. I keep getting the error

```
cannot import name PurchaseOrder
```

despite having this model

my models are

```
class Project(MAIDEAModel):
    office = models.ForeignKey(
        Office,
        related_name='projects',
        help_text=_('Office which the project is under')
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        _("Name"),
        max_length=50,
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(5), validate_sluggable],
        help_text=_('Name of the project')
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(
        _("Status"),
        choices=STATUS,
        default=STATUS_ACTIVE,
        help_text=_('Activity status of the Project')
    )
    type = models.IntegerField(
        _("Type"),
        choices=PROJECT_TYPES,
        help_text=_('Type of project')

class PurchaseOrder(MAIDEAModel):
    """ This model holds PO numbers for a project
    """
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        related_name='purchase_orders',
    )
    number = models.BigIntegerField(
        _('PO Number'),
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999999999)]
    )
```

So when I import

> from maidea.apps.somalia.models import Project, PurchaseOrder

I get an error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-6ed2e10f0c28> in <module>()
----> 1 from maidea.apps.somalia.models import PurchaseOrder

ImportError: cannot import name PurchaseOrder
```

I have tried using

```
from django.apps.import apps
apps.get_model('somalia','PurchaseOrder')
```

I get this error

```
LookupError: App 'somalia' doesn't have a 'purchaseorder' model.
```

I am running django version

```
In [28]: django.VERSION
Out[28]: (1, 9, 5, 'final', 0)
```

I kindly need help what am I missing here.
Thanks

Comment: Where are you trying to import `PurchaseOrder`? In a view?

Comment: @voodoo-burger am not importing in a view, am trying a queryset in the shell

Comment: What does `MAIDEAModel` look like?

Comment: Did you ever migrate the the model? It sounds like you haven't created a migration file and run the migration file for this model.

Comment: If you do `./manage.py dbshell`, then run `>>\dt`, do you see the table listed?